# On the proof that, if $f(x)/g(x)\to L>0$ and $f(x)\to0$, then $g(x)$ has a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $ D \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ and $ \ f, \ g \ $ are  functions from $ D \ \ to \ \ \mathbb{R} \ \ with \ \ g(x) \neq 0 , \ \ \forall  x \in D $

Suppose further that $ \ c \ $ is an accumulation point of $ \ D \ $  and $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L >0 \ $ and $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)=0 $ .

**Prove that $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) \ $ exists.**

**Answer:**

Since $ \ c \ $ is an accumulation point , $ for \ \epsilon >0 $ , $ \exists \ \delta >0 \ $ such that

$ L-\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < L+\epsilon , \ $ whenever $ \ 0 < |x-c| < \delta $ ............. $ (1) \ $

Also $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)=0 \ $ implies for the same $ \epsilon >0 \ $ , $ \ \exists \delta' >0 \ $ such that

$ -\epsilon < f(x) < \epsilon , \ whenever \ 0 < |x-c| < \delta' \ $ ..................... $(2) $

Let $ \delta_1=min\{\delta, \delta' \} $.

So from (1) and (2) , we get

$ L-\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < L+\epsilon $ ................$ (3) $  and

$ -\epsilon < f(x) < \epsilon $ .............. $(4)$

whenever $ \ 0 < |x-c| <  \delta_{1}$

Dividing $ \ (4) \ \ by \ \ (3) \ $ , we get

$ \frac{-\epsilon}{L-\epsilon} < \frac{f(x)}{f(x)/g(x)} < \frac{\epsilon}{L+\epsilon} $

or, $ 1-\frac{L}{L-\epsilon} < g(x) < 1-\frac{L}{L+\epsilon} $

Taking $ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} $ , we get

$ 1-1 < \lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) <1-1=0 $.

Hence $ \ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) \ \ exists \ \ and \ the \ limit \ is \ \ 0 \ $

**I need confirmation of my work. Am I right ? If not any help is there ?**

Comment: At least minimally informative titles, please...

Comment: You can not divide (4) by (3).

Comment: so how to manipulate in the last part ? Any help or idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Write $g (x) $ as
$$g (x)=f (x).\frac {1}{\frac {f (x)}{g (x)}} $$

and use the fact that

$$|x-c|<\delta_1\implies \frac {L}{2}< \frac {f (x)}{g (x )}<\frac {3L}{2} $$
and
$$|x-c|<\delta_2\implies |f (x)|<\epsilon \frac {L}{2} $$